# "Graphic card error" POST without a graphics card

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard

I've got a new build and I'm getting no video and an odd POST. One long beep and three short beeps on a Gigabyte, which according to [this](http://www.gigabyte.com/support-downloads/faq-page.aspx?fid=816) means a "Graphic card error", but there is no graphics card. See video of the POSTing for yourself [here](https://vid.me/v93A). The motherboard has both VGA and HDMI, and I've tried having each one plugged in individually, as well as both plugged in. No video and the same post under all combinations. Any suggestions?

Specs:

- Mobo: Gigabyte GA-F2A68HM-H
- CPU: AMD Athlon X4 845
- RAM: Crucial Ballistix Sport 8GB Single DDR3 1600 MT/s PC3-12800 CL9 1.5V UDIMM 240-Pin Memory (BLS8G3D1609DS1S00)
- PSU: EVGA 430W Power Supply (100-W1-0430-KR)

Comment: The motherboard does not have integrated video; it supports AMD APU processors which have integrated graphics. The processor that you have chosen does not have integrated graphics (it's not an AMD APU), and so the failure is real - you have no graphics card.

Comment: That was it. Repost as an answer and I'll mark it as such. Thanks!

Comment: @Argonauts - I have the same board with the same problem. Please forgive my ignorance... According to [Gigabyte's GA-F2A68HM-H](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=5262#sp) specs, there is a section *"Onboard Graphics"* and states there is an *"Integrated Graphics Processor"*. It does not discuss missing graphics processors or additional requirements. How can it have claim to have onboard/integrated graphics if it does not have it???

Comment: @Hoagy Carmichael - Do you live in ATL, GA and work for an Airline?

Comment: @jww that's creepily specific ._.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek - Its a nickname, and not his real name (I think we used to work together).